# Specman e: When colon equal sign ":=" should be used?

Tags: syntax, specman, e, colon-equals

I saw in some Specman e code example the use of **:=** (colon-equal sign), e.g.:

```
var regs_type := rf_manager.get_exact_subtype_of_instance(graphics_regs);
```

When and why should we use **:=** ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:=` means declare a variable of the type the expression on the right returns and assign it to that value. Basically, in your example, the function `get_exact_subtype_of_instance(...)` returns a value of type `rf_struct`. The `regs_type` variable will be declared to that type.

This code is equivalent to (but shorter than):

```
var regs_type : rf_struct = rf_manager.get_exact_subtype_of_instance(graphics_regs);
```

This syntax is particularly helpful when casting:

```
 var foo := some_struct.as_a(FOO some_struct_type);
```